# Service Cloud User checkbox is not available in Personal Information

Tags: administration

The `Service Cloud User` checkbox is not available in `Personal Information`. I have tried searching via <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> in Personal Information but to no avail. I am using **System Administrator standard profile** on **Unlimited edition**. I do not know where this option has been disabled for my environment. Please help.

Comment: Did you check if you have the Service Cloud feature licenses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things this could be:

1. You don't have any 'Service Cloud User' licenses - you can check this via Setup -> Administration Setup -> Company Information and scroll down to the 'Feature Licenses' section.  These are an add-on to the standard Salesforce license and require an additional payment.
2. If this is a developer edition, especially one that has been around for a while, you can have service cloud enabled by contacting support and requesting it.
3. If it is a sandbox and you have just enabled service cloud on your production org, you'll need to refresh the sandbox to bring the licenses across.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce have changed the way now, This will work

Goto - > Permission Sets - > Salesforce Console user - > App permissions - > Make sure "Allow users to access Sales Console" is checked.

Then goto -> your user page - > Permission set Assignments - > add Salesforce Console User

That's it, now you can create an app selecting console.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that user's with license "Salesforce" can only have "Service Cloud User" check box enabled even though "Service Cloud User" feature license's are available.